# Make Firefox's adressbar auto complete about URIs

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to make [about URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme) auto complete? The way I normally open the addons settings is by typing 'about:addons' into the address bar. Is there a hidden setting in 'about:config' or is there a plugin? If not is it feasible to make a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can add an `about` page  as a bookmark and it will show up in the `awesome bar. I still wonder if there are other ways though.